# IIS Rewrite Rule to get last part of dash delimited filename

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewrite-module

I am using IIS 8.5 and the rewrite module and am trying to come up with a rule to achieve the following

The actual URL
http://www.mywebsite.com/detail/name-of-my-product-3500.php

The rewrite I want to create a rule for the above example would achieve the following
http://www.mywebsite.com/detail/?id=3500

I would also be happy with anyone who has .htaccess experience to share an equivalent example as I can convert that to IIS.

So in essence my web.config rule needs to accomplish two things
1. Only apply in the /detail directory
2. Needs to pull the last part of the file name (will always be numeric)

The followign is what I come up with but this causes problems on every other url on teh site except for this within the /detail directory.

```
<rule name="Redirect to detail" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="([^-]+)\/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/detail/?npid={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="Redirect to detail" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^detail/.*-(\d+).php$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/detail/?npid={R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

Regexp `^detail/.*-(\d+).php$` will match with all URLs like that `http://www.mywebsite.com/detail/name-of-my-product-XXXXXXXX.php` and rewrite them into `/detail/?npid=XXXXXXXX`